# Что значит = function () {}

Tags: функции

```js
document.querySelector('.box').onmouseover = function () {
    ...
}
```

Пожалуйста объясните, что значит `= function () {}`. Это же не функция `arrow` или `declarations`. И почему `function` без имени. Спасибо

Comment: Это так называемые анонимные функции, если вам надо передать куда либо функцию, то для сокращения записи можете использовать такое определение.

Comment: это та же arrow функция

Comment: @eri, нет не та же

Comment: Стрелка это сахар для анонимной функции.

Comment: @eri, ну нет же.

Comment: @eri, во что по-твоему сахар должен развернуться? `function F() { this.f = () => new.target.name }
class G extends F {}
console.log(new G().f())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это function expression - функция, использованная в качестве выражения. Функции в функциональном выражении могут быть безымянными.

```js
var f = function (x, y) {
  return x + y
}

console.log(f(7, 42))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!